# How to add custom user control in master-detail mode?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, master-detail

I have a Xpf GridControl in my page. I would like to add a master-detail mode to it so that I open a custom user control under the clicked row when you click a row. The custom user control has a few comboboxes and other normal stuff with multiple lines. The master GridControl is bound to a List of objects.

I know I can add either 1) DataTemplate 2) GridControl or 3) A tabbed control containing any of these three.

I would like to add my own user control because the control would decide what data to add to the comboboxes (always the same data). Data would be added in C# side. Data in the detail view is quite different from data in the master view - they use completely different objects but have a common ID.

So, how can I add my own custom user control to the detail view? Also I naturally need to bind the user control to the master GridControl so that the user control knows which ID was clicked. Or if it's easier, I can make an aggregate class which looks something like this:

```
public class CombinedData 
{
    public DataForMaster MasterData { get; set; }
    public DataForDetail DetailData { get; set; }
}
```

I also tried to implement this with inline/inplace editors, but I only found ways to specify special cell editors, not editors for the whole row.

I believe I need to somehow use the ContentDetailDescriptor class, but all examples I found only include a GridControl, Tabbed control or a DataTemplate.

I'm quite new with WPF and a bit confused with it still. Thanks!